# Is there any way of making gdal_rasterize or gdal_translate create transparent pixels on the output image created?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, gdal-rasterize

I'm using the `gdal_rasterize` to create a TIFF file from a GeoJSON input and `gdal_translate` to convert the TIFF file to PNG. The code that I'm using is the following:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 0 -burn 0 -burn 255 -ot Byte -tr 0.0000169959 0.0000169959 input.geojson image.tif
gdal_translate -of PNG -ot Byte -scale image.tif output.png
```

Both the `png` and `tif` files result in the following image:

[image]

Even though it works for generating the blue geometries inside the image, the result has a black background on it. I'd like my final result on the `png` file to have a transparent background (not black), keeping only the blue lines... Is there any extra parameter I can use with `gdal_rasterize` or `gdal_translate` in order to exclude the black pixels from my image?

Comment: How about `nodata`? See [docs](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html)

Comment: Or  `-a_nodata` in gdal_rasterize, see the docs https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burn a 4th band with 255, set it as the alpha channel.

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 0 -burn 0 -burn 255 -burn 255 -ot Byte -tr 0.0000169959 0.0000169959 input.geojson image.tif
gdal_translate -of PNG -ot Byte -colorinterp red,green,blue,alpha image.tif output.png
```

Or

Set a value to be nodata in `gdal_rasterize` to a value not used as a burn value.

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 0 -burn 0 -burn 255 -a_nodata 1 -ot Byte -tr 0.0000169959 0.0000169959 input.geojson image.tif
gdal_translate -of PNG image.tif output.png
```